# Change version of product

Tags: tycho

I have a very basic project setup without sub-modules or anything. Just a *pom.xml* with nothing fancy:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.acme.product</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.acme.product</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.9</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.26.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>0.26.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <resolver>p2</resolver>
                    <target>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.acme.product</groupId>
                            <artifactId>org.acme.product</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                            <classifier>platform</classifier>
                        </artifact>
                    </target>
                    <ignoreTychoRepositories>true</ignoreTychoRepositories>
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Of course there is a target platform named *platform.target* with the feature `org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature.group`. Finally there is a (empty) product with the same ID and version.

Now I want to use Tycho to update this version. It's only two files, I know. Still.

```
mvn org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-versions-plugin:set-version -DnewVersion=1.0.0
```

The *pom.xml* will get updated, but the product not. The same thing works with plug-ins and features, I can't figure out why it won't work with products, too.

Can somebody help to change the product's version?

Comment: I misread your question, therefore I deleted my answer which considered multiple modules.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your pom.xml version and product version are the same.

> The versions-plugin will only update the versions in product files if the old version matches the version in the eclipse-repository POM.
>   Product files whose versions are (intentionally) different from the POM version are not updated. This is the same as with modules: modules which don't have the same version as the root POM are not updated.

Refer to this bug [report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=358292)

Comment: Yes, they are the same. The exact same setup works when I insert a build project above the product module.

Comment: Maybe despite the <classifier>platform</classifier> Tycho is looking for a *org.acme.product.target* file, instead of *platform.target*? Also try using the latests Tycho version 1.3.0

Comment: I tried renaming the target and the latest Tycho, still no luck. (Which is too say, I still use the workaround of having a build project around the product so it does work.)